# xero invoice description break line

Tags: php, xero-api

I had find and tried many way such as:

\n

.PHP_EOL

`&#xD;`

`&#xA;`

but when open the billing it not break line, does anyone had success break line?

my example code: `$line_item->setDescription($item->description."\n \n \n");`

Comment: Have you try \r\n ?
Or on html we can use <br> to make line break.

Comment: I already use <br>, and it show the element "<br>" in description.
I think they had trim(\n, , ...) so the break line and space had been remove, i don't know is there any way to prevent it

Comment: Hope this help. https://github.com/calcinai/xero-php/issues/447
He try manually make line break on his code.

Comment: Thanks @AriAbimanyu, he break line with text behind so that working, but i just want break line but it had been clear, so i thing they trim it.